# Outlook addin custom pop up form

Tags: outlook, add-in, ribbon

i am creating an addin for outlook . i am stuck with my requirements ... how to open a pop up for entering some input value on click of custom button in ribbon.

i.e How to open a form in outlook UI

Answer (score 0):

simple question it was ..

i am able to open vb form ..

NativeAddIn::ApplicationConfiguration ^appConfigurationform = gcnew NativeAddIn::ApplicationConfiguration();
        appConfigurationform->ShowDialog();

Answer (score 0):

To create a ribbon in the outlook 
Click on file - go to options - customize ribbon - create a new tab - rename it by clicking on it next drag an action to be performed on the particular ribbon 
and import settings
click ok 
close the outllok and reopen it again

this is for outlook application 2019.